# Possible to add another item to an existing enum type?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, enums

I wonder whether it is possible to add/append another item to an existing enum type (part of a framework)?

Something like this: We have the `enum` type

```
  typedef enum {  
    UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,  
    UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
    UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
    UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
 } UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

Now I want to append or add to this set an item like `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVerticalFlipped`.
Can something like this be accomplished?

Comment: If you have the source of the framework, you can do this and any other modifications you like.

Comment: What you want to do makes perfect sense.  Unfortunately, enums cannot really be extended externally the way, for example, classes can be (via inheritance, etc. etc.).

Answer (score 17):

You can force new element to have the same type as the enum, but you can't extend it in a subclass.
header file:

```
extern const UIModalTransitionStyle UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVerticalFlipped;
```

implementation file:

```
const UIModalTransitionStyle UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVerticalFlipped = 10;
```

Make sure to give some space in case the framework is extended, so that you don't have conflicts. This is a bit of a hack, but it will get rid of compiler errors and warnings.

Comment: plus1 for Make sure to give some space

Answer (score 8):

To do it, you have to modify the original type definition to include the new value:

```
typedef enum {  
    UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,  
    UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
    UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
    UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
    UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVerticalFlipped
} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

Otherwise, you can take a chance on its not working, and define it separately:

```
typedef enum {  
    UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,  
    UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
    UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
    UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
} UIModalTransitionStyle;

typedef enum { 
    UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVerticalFlipped =
        UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl + 1
} ExtendedUIModalTransitionStyle;
```

A variable that could hold the original enumeration will *usually* also work perfectly fine when/if you assign the new value as well (in a typical case, it'll just be an `int`) -- but it's *not* guaranteed. At least in theory, the implementation can/could assign few enough bits to hold that enumeration that it adding more values this way wouldn't work. It could also do range checking so assigning *any* out of range value wouldn't be allowed. Neither of these is at all common, so from a practical viewpoint it's probably not a problem -- but from a theoretical viewpoint, nothing really guarantees that code like this will work.

Comment: Thanks for the two possible approaches. I will go with the second one.

Comment: @Jerry approach 2 assumes that Apple are not going to add another type(s) after UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl in future SDK versions, of which then you would get a conflict(s).

Comment: @pnizzle: Yes, that's (part of) why I specifically said: "you can take a chance on its not working ..."

Comment: in later Xcode versions (9.1) extending a enum gives you a warning `Comparison of constant 'ScannerStatusNotInitialized' (-1) with expression of type 'ScannerStatus' (aka 'enum ScannerStatus') is always false`, even tho that is not true. 
@pnizzle, you can define it as Flipped = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl + 666, to increase your chances, but you have to give up your soul :|

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, BaseType) {
    BaseTypeCase1,
    BaseTypeCase2,
    BaseTypeSize
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SubType) {
    SubTypeCase1 = BaseTypeSize,
    SubTypeCase2
};
```

Now you can switch on SubType knowing the values are unique.

If you don't have access to BaseType, you could set SubTypeCase1 to BaseType's last item + 1.

Downside is, you can't declare a method that takes a SubType and pass to it a BaseType without getting a compiler warning. So you need to declare your methods to take NSIntegers in order silence that warning.
Also, it feels weird when you need to declare a parameter of SubType and be able to pass in a BaseType.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to update the Enum declaration to include `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVerticalFlipped` this values as well

```
typedef enum {      
 UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,       
 UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,     
 UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,     
 UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,     
 UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVerticalFlipped 
} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

so `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVerticalFlipped` will be equivalent to integer constant 4

whereever you use any string constant from Enum dec. corresponding constant value get replaced so it is used to constraint the variable to hold only specified set of values only(i.e. 0  to 4) in above mentioned case