# Is there a way to add new items to enum in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to add another item to an existing enum type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124012/possible-to-add-another-item-to-an-existing-enum-type)

Say I have a class `Car` with the following enum defined:

```
typedef enum
{
    DrivingForward,
    DrivingBackward
} DrivingState;
```

Then, let's say I have a subclass of `Car` called `Tesla` and it happens to drive sideways too. Is there a way for `Tesla` to add new items to that original enum so that the final enum becomes like the following?

```
typedef enum
{
    DrivingForward,
    DrivingBackward,
    DrivingLeft,
    DrivingRight
} DrivingState;
```

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124012/possible-to-add-another-enum-item-to-an-existing-enum-type

Comment: Okay, thanks. Seems like the answer is no, you can't.