# Cordova Media Plugin doesn't implement audioPlayerEndInterruption

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, plugins, avaudioplayer

I have created an iOS app that plays audio while the app is running in the background. If the audio is ever interrupted (i.e.: phone call), the audio stops and never resumes.

I think this is because the cordova media plugin doesn't implement audioPlayerEndInterruption

I'm good with Javascript but know almost nothing about Objective-C. Does anyone have advice on how to add this functionality?

Is there a different media plugin that implements audioPlayerEndInterruption, or is there a simple way to incorporate audioPlayerEndInterruption into the cordova plugin?

Comment: what version of cordova?

Comment: I'm using v3.1 right now but I'm planning to switch over to v3.5 soon.

Comment: I can throw some 3.2 code changes at you, if you want to test it out. You should be able to modify the CDVSound.h/.m files and the media.js to handle audioPlayerEndInterruption.

Comment: ok. That would be great. I'm actually using AppGyver Steroids which is a layer on top of PhoneGap, so I can't edit the plugin directly. But I'm assuming that if I fork the Cordova Media Plugin and make the change, then I can import it into my project via plugman. Hopefully that will just overwrite the default plugin?

Comment: Yeah, not sure how Steroids is implemented, but if you can add custom plugins, then you should be able to find a way. fwiw, if the code doesn't work for you, it should be pretty close...just trying to give you the steps necessary ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following up here. I ended up writing a plugin for this that overwrites some of the default cordova media plugin (v0.2.12) methods. I'm posting a link here, but the code is a mess. I was just trying to get something that works and not really planning on sharing. But here it is (no documentation provided, sorry):

https://github.com/stevethorson/Interruptible-Cordova-Media.git

Answer (score 2):

**CDVSound.h**
-modify:add: , MEDIA_END_INTERRUPT = 5

```
enum CDVMediaStates {
    MEDIA_NONE = 0,
    MEDIA_STARTING = 1,
    MEDIA_RUNNING = 2,
    MEDIA_PAUSED = 3,
    MEDIA_STOPPED = 4,
    MEDIA_END_INTERRUPT = 5
};
```

**CDVSound.m**
-add:

```
- (void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer*)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    CDVAudioPlayer* aPlayer = (CDVAudioPlayer*)player;
    NSString* mediaId = aPlayer.mediaId;
    CDVAudioFile* audioFile = [[self soundCache] objectForKey:mediaId];
    NSString* jsString = nil;

    if (audioFile != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Ended Interruption of playing audio sample '%@'", audioFile.resourcePath);
    }
    if (flag) {
        jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(\"%@\",%d,%d);", @"cordova.require('org.apache.cordova.media.Media').onStatus", mediaId, MEDIA_STATE, MEDIA_END_INTERRUPT];
    } else {
        jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(\"%@\",%d,%@);", @"cordova.require('org.apache.cordova.media.Media').onStatus", mediaId, MEDIA_ERROR, [self createMediaErrorWithCode:MEDIA_ERR_DECODE message:nil]];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate evalJs:jsString];
}
```

**Media.js**
-modify:add: Media.MEDIA_END_INTERRUPT = 5; AND , "EndInterrupt"

```
// Media states
Media.MEDIA_NONE = 0;
Media.MEDIA_STARTING = 1;
Media.MEDIA_RUNNING = 2;
Media.MEDIA_PAUSED = 3;
Media.MEDIA_STOPPED = 4;
Media.MEDIA_END_INTERRUPT = 5;
Media.MEDIA_MSG = ["None", "Starting", "Running", "Paused", "Stopped", "EndInterrupt"];
```

Then find Media.onStatus = function(id, msgType, value) { and add a conditional in the case Media.MEDIA_STATE : block...

```
 if(value == Media.MEDIA_END_INTERRUPT) {
     //do whatever you want
 }
```

Comment: I'm using a platform called Steroids which sits on top of cordova. Because of this, I can not edit the media plugin directly. So I'm trying to extend it, but with my lack of Objective-C knowledge, I'm really just stabbing in the dark. I've done my best to try to structure the code you provided into an extended class [here](https://github.com/stevethorson/Interruptible-Cordova-Media), but I'm getting a compile error about trying to redeclare the enum CDVMediaStates. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is a way to override an enum. That's kinda why I didn't offer a category/ext. Can you just dupe the entire CDVSound plugin (enhanced) and then replace theirs with yours in the config.xml?

Comment: well, Jerry Coffin has an qualified alternative you could try in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124012/possible-to-add-another-item-to-an-existing-enum-type

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem from within the media plugin itself, using the getCurrentPosition method I was able to detect if the streaming gets intrupted by a phone call or voicemail.. and then stop and rePlay the audio again. I hope this helps someone I took me forever to get this working with the media plugin and shoutcast.

```js
var mediaplayer = new Media(streamingUrl, mediaSuccess, mediaFail, mediaState);
mediaplayer.play({playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked :true});

var prevPos = 0;
        var mediaTimer = setInterval(function () {
            // get media position
            mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition(
                // success callback
                function (currentposition) {
                    if (currentposition > prevPos) {                        
                        prevPos = currentposition;                        
                    } else if (currentposition === prevPos) {                   
                        stop();
                        play();
                    } else {
                        console.log("can't get pos");
                    }
                },
                // error callback
                function (e) {
                    alert+("Error getting pos=" + e);
                }
            );
        }, 5000);
```