# How to redefine a enum in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say we got a super class named `BaseViewController`, in whose `.h` file defined a enum as the following.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, SectionType) {
    SectionTypeUserName,
    SectionTypeUserAddress,
    ...
    SectionTypeUserPets
}
```

This enum is the type of the section in a table view.

Now, I got another view controller named `ASubViewController` which is inherited from `BaseViewController`.

Because the section type now is a little bit different like the below, how to insert a new element at the head of if.

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, SectionType) {
    SectionTypeUserTitle, // Just insert this line
    SectionTypeUserName,
    SectionTypeUserAddress,
    ...
    SectionTypeUserPets
}

Because nothing of the rest code need any modification. The defualt setting is enough.
So how to implement it?

Comment: I don't think the Enum would be accessible in your child controller. So you can just re-use this enum name in your child controller.

Comment: Yeah, of course it can't be accessed. This a wrong example. My point is how to redefine it. I will update it.

Comment: Ok now it makes sense.
Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45099817/1996025

Comment: Enums cannot be changed or overriden. They are not even a part of the class. I would say that even inheritance of these two controllers is a bad idea. Dont create random subclasses to reuse implementation, refactor the base controller instead or create a common superclass for both.

Comment: While, it does inspire me. But actually my purpose is insert a new element at the head of the enum! I will update my question again.

Comment: @Sulthan I think you are right. I will think about it.